# RPy2, subset data frame with multiple conditions

Tags: python, r, dataframe, subset, rpy2

I have a data frame with, amongst others, 2 columns called data_type and input_type.

To obtain the subset of the data frame where data_type column has a certain value I can use:

```
subset_frame = dataframe.rx(dataframe.rx2('input_type').ro == 'VALUE', True)
```

I can do the same on column input_type. However I haven't managed to work out how to combine these 2 conditions in one operation. From the rpy2 docs, what I expect should work is

```
new_frame = dataframe.rx((dataframe.rx2('input_type').ro == 'VALUE1').ro 
                              & dataframe.rx2('data_type').ro == 'VALUE2').ro, 
                              True)
```

However this also doesn't work. What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `.ro` is in excess:

```
new_frame = all_data_frame.rx((dataframe.rx2('input_type').ro == 'VALUE1').ro 
                               & (dataframe.rx2('data_type').ro == 'VALUE2'), 
                              True)
```

Otherwise this might change to `and`, not `&`. The later is a bitwise operator in Python.

```
>>> 1 & 2 # 0b01 & 0b10
0
>>> 1 & 3 # 0b01 & 0b11
1
```

Comment: I was using & based on this example in the docs
    `>>> i = (x.ro >= 2 ).ro & (x.ro <= 4)` # extract values between 2 and 4

Comment: Ah. I dashed on the keyboard too hastily: this might be a mistake in rpy2's API. Otherwise, the example in the documentation is showing why this is not working for you. I edited my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Still not working, this is the error: `ValueError: Nothing can be done for the type <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.VectorOperationsDelegator'> at the moment.`

Comment: Ah yes removing the second .ro is the trick. It needs parentheses around the second condition though to work (you seem to have accidentally missed the opening one in your example) otherwise it still raises an error. Thanks!